# Can someone tell me the time complexity of my solution to this problem of zigag traversal

Tags: python, arrays, time, time-complexity, zigzag

## ZigZag traversal

This is one of the question from algoexpert and this is my solution involving math

```
def zigzagTraversal(arr):
out = []
test = 1
out.append(arr[0][0])
while test <= len(arr)+len(arr[0]):
    for j in range(len(arr[0])):
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            if test % 2 == 1:
                if i + j == test:
                    # print(arr[i][j])
                    out.append(arr[i][j])
            else:
                if i + j == test:
                    out.append(arr[j][i])
    test += 1
return out
print(zigzagTraversal([[1, 3, 4, 10],
                   [2, 5, 9, 11],
                   [6, 8, 12, 15],
                   [7, 13, 14, 16]]))
```

Comment: I haven't busted out the calculus in a long time, but... You are traversing a 2D array, and you are doing row + col times.  If your array is n x n in size your complexity is 2n x n^2, which if I remember my reducing rules comes out to roughly o(n^2).  I am curious to see if someone does full analysis for you.

Comment: @codingCat if the OP isn't interested in feedback about any or all facets of the code then it wouldn't really be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR. Please refer to [this meta answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8374/120114) (and its siblings) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `N=len(arr), M=len(arr[0])`. This code has `O(NM^2+N^2M)` complexity (or `O(N^3)` for square input matrix). Here's why: outer loop (`while`) is fully equivalent to `for` loop (because you increment `test` at the end and never change it elsewhere) and will be executed `N+M` times. Then you enter the second loop which is executed exactly `N` times. Then inner loop - `M` times. Inner loop will be repeated for each step of middle loop, the same with outer. So we have to multiply all this counts together. All inner operations are not atomic, of course, but for small data will be `O(1)` on average. If your input is large, I suggest pre-allocating `out` (creating it as `out = [None for _ in range(N*M)]`) to avoid costs of its growth and keeping current first free index as additional variable.